# How do I make my React Components to be responsive via css media queries?

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

I have this site that I'm currently trying to convert into react with css media query for phone & tablet.

The problem I just encountered is that the css for the `media query` doesn't get read or simply doesn't work in React.

Any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: You could look into frameworks like [aphrodite](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite). They support media queries and conditional styles.

Comment: Can you track a piece of code as an example on how you're trying to achieve this?

Comment: @FabianSchultz I'll probably use that since it has support for fonts as well

Comment: @EdmarMiyake basically I have `media queries` already but React doesn't read it if I'm correct. So basically I'm finding a solution on how to use these `media queries` that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries has nothing to do with React, as long as you don't use inline CSS because at the end  react outputs HTML and media queries works perfect.

I built entire front-end in react and made it pure responsive. Also i used only 1% css as inline and am using two frameworks
1. Semantic-ui 
2. Flexbox Grid

along with below media queries ( written less variables).

```
@highdensity: ~"only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)",
              ~"only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)",
              ~"only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2)",
              ~"only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)";
@mobile:      ~"only screen and (max-width: 529px)";
@tablet:      ~"only screen and (min-width: 530px) and (max-width: 949px)";
@desktop:     ~"only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1128px)";
@desktop-xl:  ~"only screen and (min-width: 1129px)";
@desktop-above: ~"only screen and (min-width: 950px)";
@tablet-above: ~"only screen and (min-width: 530px)";
@mobile-above: ~"only screen and (min-width: 320px)";
```

Comment: oh really? I didnt realize about that. Thanks a bunch! My friend hard coded some css styles so I didn't know that was the main problem. Thanks again.

Comment: 1st, don't use inline css,  Apply class or style to component and use normal css/less and require it in component file or your page directly.

Comment: I do use classes or ids, its just that my friend did those pages and I was just converting to jsx then I found out the problem. But thanks for the clarification, it really helped to ease things out.